# Azure Iot sdk - upload blob metadata?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

It's great that Azure Iot hub and sdk supports blob uploading. However it seems blob metadata uploading is not there. Any plan to add the feature? It's a very handy feature for small projects.

Or it's already supported but I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. There is no method (support) for the blob metadata uploading in the *Azure IoT Device Client SDK*. 
However, the following workaround can be used for this feature. It's based on the [uploading files with IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload) using the REST API calls.

Step 1: The device ask an Azure IoT Hub for upload references
[image: Step1]

Step 2: Upload blob and metadata
[image: Step2]

Step3: Complete the device uploading process:
[image: Step3]

Comment: Thanks Roman. This definitely works but it still seems to much move convenient to me to have it directly supported in the file uploading function in the SDK - especially given that it's a direct blob upload.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is tracked by https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/165 for the .NET Azure IoT SDK.